# How can I add more data to an json based object in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am trying to add more things inside an object but I am not sure how to do it

I have tried pushing the data into the object but it doesn't work

```
people = [{
  name: 'robert',
  year: 1993
}];
```

//this is what i want to add

```
people = {
  name: 'joe',
  year: 1992
}
```

//I want it to act as if it was

```
people = [{
  name: 'robert',
  year: 1993
}, {
  name: 'joe',
  year: 1992
}];
```

I want to be able to call it back using 
people[0].name

Comment: It's typescript, call the `Person` out for what they are. `people` as `{}[]` and `people` as `{}` is confusing. Singular of `people` is `Person` so try `Person[]` where `Person` is a well-defined type.

Comment: "How can I add more data to an json based object in Typescript?" -- by extension or composition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the `people` variable to be an array of objects,

```
const people = [{ name: 'robert', year: 1993 }];
```

If you want to add an object to `people`,

```
const newPerson = { name: 'joe', year: 1992 };
people.push(newPerson);
```

And if you want to access the individual objects/properties,

```
people[0];
people[0]['name'];
```

Regarding your subsequent issue, you may want to provide the type definitions for `people`.

```
export class AppComponents { 
  // your properties and methods
}

interface Person {
  name: string;
  year: number; 
}
```

On your main code itself, you can declare the variables with the typings.

```
const people: Person[] = [{ name: 'robert', year: 1993 }];
const newPerson: Person = { name: 'joe', year: 1992 };
people.push(newPerson);
```

Comment: I added that and got an error saying Subsequent property declarations must have the same type. Property 'people' must be of type '{name: string; year: number; } [ ] ' , but here has type 'any' . ts (2717)

Comment: @RobertoMejia I see.. Hmm, I have updated my code to include the Interface so that we can use it to provide the type definitions for our objects/arrays. Let me know if it solves the issue?

Comment: When I placed the interface it gives me an error saying Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor or property was expected.

Comment: Ok ermm.. Where did you place the interface

Comment: I placed it inside the AppComponent class, so inside the class I have, the interface and the last 3 lines of code that you gave me that start with,  const people: Person[], const newPerson: Person, and people.push

Comment: You shouldn't place it within the appcomponent class. Treat it as a separate class. Let me update my answer

Comment: It worked! thank you, so how come we don't put the interface inside the class?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
people.push({ name: 'joe', year: 1992 });
```

Comment: I added that and got an error saying      Subsequent property declarations must have the same type. Property 'people' must be of type '{name: string; year: number; } [ ] ' , but here has type 'any' . ts (2717)

Comment: make sure the person which you are pushing has exact type.

Comment: yes just exactly as you have it, I tried it out and it gave me that error

Comment: can you share person class code here and what you are pushing that too?

Comment: import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'hi';

  people = [{
    name: 'robert',
    year: 1993
  }];

  people.push({ name: 'joe', year: 1992 });

Comment: thats inside app.component.ts